# Convert MongoDB Date format to String in Python (without using dateToString)

Tags: python, mongodb, date

I would like to convert a MongoDB Date Object to a string.

**However, I am unable to use the "dateToString" operator because I am running MongoDB 2.6 and do not have the option to upgrade at this time.**

What should I use instead?

Query:

```
computer = db['cmp_host'].aggregate([
        {"$project":{
            "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4",
            #"u_updated_timestamp": "$last_seen",
            #"u_updated_timestamp": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$last_seen" } }
            }
         }
        ])
```

Current MongoDB Date format (needs to be converted to human readable string):

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 12, 5, 18, 521000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 12, 5, 18, 521000)` is a Python datetime type, not MongoDB's.

To convert it into a string, you can use Python datetime's `strftime()` method. For example:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 12, 5, 18, 521000)

>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2016-09-02'

>>> d.strftime('%c')
'Fri Sep  2 12:05:18 2016'
```

The full description of `strftime()` is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: thank you, any idea how I would do that in the context of the mongodb query? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any method to do that in MongoDB 2.6, unfortunately. If upgrading is not an option, then post-processing the result would be the easiest solution. However I would encourage you to upgrade anyway, since MongoDB 2.6 is reaching its end-of-life and would not be supported soon.